# Don't know what to work on next

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

I'm currently working on a 2D platformer, and I have no idea what to add next. I've created the code for the player, the animations for the player(just the player for now so that I don't get burnt out), basic player functionality, and I'm just completely dumbfounded on what to do next. Of course I have big plans, including story, cutscenes, the rest of the graphics, level design, etc., but I just feel like I need to continue more of the basics and the "basics" doesn't feel like it's completed yet for me to move forward. I feel like there's a bridge between working on the big things and small things in this game, and I don't want to just jump forward and start working on story or level design when the fundamentals might not even be finished. Sorry if this is all a bit rambly by the way.

Comment: If you make a small scene of an example level, do you have everything to play it as you envision your game later to be played? If not, start with that.

Comment: Related: [How can I effectively manage a hobby game project?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/85/40264)

Comment: As-is, this question is a bit open-ended. But the premise is great. Can you edit the question to be more narrow? Perhaps along the lines of, 'How can I prioritize the tasks for my game, such that I meet my goals?'  While listing what those goals are, whether they be financial, time-based, or motivational.  And also listing at a high level what tasks you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would focus on making one example/ showcase scene that contains everything that you envision later to be in your game.

That way you can test all elements of your game, see if they are working as they should, need tweeking or if something crucial is missing. This gives you as well a small piece that you can give others for a first feedback or if you just want to show it to other people.

- A story line can be broken down in a single interaction with one npc
  to test if your dialog system is working.
- That npc might give a kill or fetch quest
- You already have the animations done for your player, maybe adding a simple one for one enemy to test combat.
- Placing skill checks in your game. If you have a double jump, having a pit that can only cleared by a double jump. Wall jump. Dash test. Whatever your game has to offer.

This demo scene can later be used as part of a tutorial as well. All your big plans are later build on top of it.

You know the basic is done when it is working in your example scene. You can do a double jump? Don't second guess your code. If it works, it is good enough to focus on the next thing in the list. No code is ever fully finished, perfectly written, can't be in one or three ways be refactored or otherway adjusted. Focus on bringing functionality to it and move to the next basic block once one is done.

If you are done with what makes your game your game, you build on top of these building blocks with story, levels, graphic improvement and everything else. If you have a great idea, just write it down so you don't forget it later.

Answer (score 1):

My first priority in every game project I participate in is to create a [minimum viable product](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvCri1tqIxQ) (MVP). An MVP is the simplest, quickest and dirtiest possible implementation of your game which can be playtested and deliver you useful data.

The MVP for a platformer would be a simple test level with the player being able to jump and run. If you want to create a platformer in this day and age which actually sells, then you also need some unique gimmick. If you do have such an unique gimmick in mind as a core part of your game idea, then it should also be part of the MVP to prove that the concept works. If you don't, then don't worry. You will certainly come up with *something* over the course of the next months.

The MVP doesn't need to be pretty or interesting. It just needs to demonstrate the core mechanic of your game.

Now you can test your core mechanic. You can find out if it even works the way you pictured it and if it is fun to play. You might have to tweak it a bit to get good "game-feel". That is particularly important in a platformer, because the way the character jumps and runs will affect every single level, obstacle and mechanic you add later. That means it can get really expensive to make changes to the character's moveset at a later point in the development process. For example, when you later find out that the game would be more fun if the player's jump would be 10 pixels shorter, then you need to revise every single level you already created to make sure it's still solvable. You really don't want that, so take your time with your test level and make sure you got the basic player controls exactly the way you want them.

With that, you created a solid foundation you can build on. Now you can, for example:

- Add enemies and other hazards
- Add special abilities
- Create actual levels
- Create special objects within levels that interact in fun(?) ways with the character's abilities
- Work on your art assets so your ugly test level with those ugly placeholder characters gets closer to the final look you want the game to have
- Add juice like sound effects or particles

Which one do you start with? Well, which one do you *want* to start with? At this point of development, you still have total freedom what you want to tackle first. Try any of the above things, playtest the result, and then decide if you want to keep, revise or discard the thing you just added.